# flask deployment to heroku

Tags: flask, heroku

[image: heroku db]using flask app, my Procfile is "web: gunicorn app:app",   my app file name is "app"

Any ideas what went wrong ?

below shows the log

```
2020-05-29T18:45:44.045795+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.stop()
2020-05-29T18:45:44.045832+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 393, in stop
2020-05-29T18:45:44.046212+00:00 app[web.1]:     time.sleep(0.1)
2020-05-29T18:45:44.046246+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 244, in handle_chld
2020-05-29T18:45:44.046532+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.reap_workers()
2020-05-29T18:45:44.046569+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 524, in reap_workers
2020-05-29T18:45:44.047026+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
2020-05-29T18:45:44.047104+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
2020-05-29T18:45:44.144366+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-05-29T18:45:44.201658+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Comment: are you sure that the procfile is committed? If yes can you update your question so we can see the whole structure of your project blueprint?

Comment: Hi Patch, how do i check if Procfile is committed ? is it through git?

Comment: Try to commit your program to see if there are any changes. Can you please show me a line by line of how you commit?

Comment: Hi Patch, I just noticed after letting the website run longer and more codes starts to appear. this is all the codes that is generated -     https://pastebin.com/E1JAgYag

Comment: Are you using sleep in your code by any chance? If the answer is no can you send me your whole code in pastebin?

Comment: there is no sleep, this is the app file   :     https://pastebin.com/giQUUqZq

Comment: Do you have pipenv, requirements.txt etc? Update your question so it will have the project blueprint(his structure). I think I know what the problem is but I need to make sure you have it set up right

Comment: yes, i installed pipenv.  here is the link for requirements.txt  :    https://pastebin.com/JdWMFC3n

Comment: Did you pipenv install everything?

Comment: i did pip install pipenv, pipenv install.  heres the file : https://pastebin.com/MxZeimU2

Answer (score 0):

The problem Is that you are trying to connect to a db that doesn't exist. In your code you are connecting to a localhost postgresql db. [You need to open a db in heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql)

Comment: Hi Patch, yes I did have a db and it is connected to heroku app. pic attached at the top

Comment: In the code you sent me you didn't have you have the same msg? You don't need to just create it you need to link it too

Comment: how do i link the db  through heroku ? I am using postgresql

Comment: I linked it in my answer.

Comment: i have read thr the instructions but I hope not to make mistake, could you point to me that are these commands that i should be having to connect postgressql to heroku ?         ```            pip install psycopg2-binary    import os
import psycopg2

DATABASE_URL = os.environ['DATABASE_URL']

conn = psycopg2.connect(DATABASE_URL, sslmode='require')     ```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215053/discussion-between-anon-and-patch).